# Working on a Dynamics CRM Custom Workflow that updates "Modified By" field -- need help debugging

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow

I am working on a **Dynamics CRM CWA** that updates the "Modified By" field based on a text field called "Prepared By".  I currently have 3 errors that I need some help debugging (see below).  They may be pretty easy fixes but I am fairly new to coding.  Any help de-bugging would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace KED365.Workflows
{


    /// </summary>    
    public class ModifiedBy : WorkFlowActivityBase
    {
        private Guid contactid;

        [Input("User Full Name")]
        public InArgument<string> UserFullName { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the WorkFlow.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="crmWorkflowContext">The <see cref="LocalWorkflowContext"/> which contains the
        /// <param name="executionContext" > <see cref="CodeActivityContext"/>
        /// </param>       
        /// <remarks>
        /// For improved performance, Microsoft Dynamics 365 caches WorkFlow instances.
        /// The WorkFlow's Execute method should be written to be stateless as the constructor
        /// is not called for every invocation of the WorkFlow. Also, multiple system threads
        /// could execute the WorkFlow at the same time. All per invocation state information
        /// is stored in the context. This means that you should not use global variables in WorkFlows.
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext activityContext, IWorkflowContext workflowContext, IOrganizationService orgService, ITracingService tracingService)
        {
            //get entity record for which plugin was fired
            Entity _target = (Entity)workflowContext.InputParameters["Target"];


            //check if portaluser name is to be obtained from custom createby or from custom modifiedby
            if (workflowContext.MessageName.ToUpper() == "CREATE")
            {
                contactid = _target.Attributes.Contains("new_createdby") ? _target.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_createdby").Id : Guid.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                contactid = _target.Attributes.Contains("new_modifiedby") ? _target.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_modifiedby").Id : Guid.Empty;
            }

            //retrieve contact fullname from contactid
            var _contact = activityContext.CreateQuery("contact").Where(c => c.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("contactid").Equals(contactid)).FirstOrDefault();


            if (_contact != null)
            {
                if (_contact.Attributes.Contains("fullname"))
                {
                    fullname = _contact.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname");
                }

                //retrieve Systemuser that has same name as that of new_portalcreatedby/ //new_portalmodifiedby
                Entity _user = context.CreateQuery("systemuser").Where(e => e.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname").Equals(fullname)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (_user != null)
                {

                    //check if we need to update createdby or modifiedby
                    if (workflowContext.MessageName.ToUpper() == "CREATE")
                    {
                        _target["createdby"] = _user.ToEntityReference();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _target["modifiedby"] = _user.ToEntityReference();
                    }

                    //assign new target to plugin executioncontext
                    workflowContext.InputParameters["Target"] = _target;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error 1 :**

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'CodeActivityContext' does not contain a definition for 'CreateQuery' and no extension method 'CreateQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'CodeActivityContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Workflows   C:\Users\tgiard\Downloads\GetUserByName-master\GetUserByName-master\Workflows\ModifiedBy.cs 68  Active

**Error 2 :**

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'fullname' does not exist in the current context   Workflows   C:\Users\tgiard\Downloads\GetUserByName-master\GetUserByName-master\Workflows\ModifiedBy.cs 75  Active

**Error 3 :**

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'context' does not exist in the current context    Workflows   C:\Users\tgiard\Downloads\GetUserByName-master\GetUserByName-master\Workflows\ModifiedBy.cs 79  Active

Comment: Curious why you are using a CWA rather than an ordinary plug-in for this. You have defined an InputParameter, but you aren't using it anywhere in your code.

Guidance for Custom workflow activities is that you should define input and output parameters so that someone using the custom activity in the designer can see what it is doing. You would want to update the value with the output of the custom activity rather than working with the Target parameter directly. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/workflow/workflow-extensions#get-contextual-information

Comment: @JimDaly-MSFT-, whats the difference between a CWA and an ordinary plug-in?  I was under the impression they are the same thing.
Also, any advice on where I should be using the InputParameter?  This is all fairly new to me so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.
Thanks!

Comment: Recommend you start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/apply-business-logic-with-code
Keep in mind that CRM uses the platform now known as Common Data Service.
Custom Workflow Assemblies, a.k.a. Workflow extensions are intended to provide UI to extend the workflow designer. Plug-ins are registered for events and have no UI.

Comment: I agree with Jim, this code should be in a plugin

Answer (score 1):

Here is some feedback on your issues:

**Error 1** - *'CodeActivityContext' does not contain a definition for 'CreateQuery'*
This issue is related to the lines:

```
var _contact = activityContext.CreateQuery("contact").Where(c => c.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("contactid").Equals(contactid)).FirstOrDefault();
```

and

```
Entity _user = context.CreateQuery("systemuser").Where(e => e.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname").Equals(fullname)).FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't know what that method is but you have better options; for the contact you already have the guid, so you can simply use a Retrieve():

```
    var _contact = orgService.Retrieve("contact", contactid, new ColumnSet("fullname"));
```

And for the system user write a QueryExpression filtering by fullname:

```
var query = new QueryExpression("systemuser"):
query.Criteria.AddCondition("fullname", ConditionOperator.Equal, fullname);
var _user = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.FirstOrDefault();
```

**Error 2:** *The name 'fullname' does not exist in the current contex* 
This is basic C#, you  must instantiate your variable before you use it:

```
string fullname;
```

**Error 3:** *The name 'context' does not exist in the current context*
Ironic and true. This should be activityContext, but we have already fixed this issue in the change we made for Error 1.

```
Entity _user = context.CreateQuery("systemuser").Where(e => e.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname").Equals(fullname)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks @Zach!  I was able to get rid of each of the errors using your suggestions.  I deployed the custom workflow step into CRM but am getting the following error when I run the workflow: SandboxFault.ThrowIfGuidEmpty: entityId
Any ideas on how I can fix this?
My workflow is triggered when the "Prepared By" field is updated.  I then use the custom workflow step and have whatevers in the "Prepared By" field as the input for this step.

Comment: I think rather than trying to troubleshoot this issue you should re-work your code to run in a pre-create / pre-update plugin as recommended by Jim. Much of the actual code will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Zach Mast correctly pointed out, using a Pre-Operation is recommended. It also seems an odd case where you retrieve a contacts name and match it with a user. Instead, You could change the type of the field to a user reference, add a user field to the contact you retrieve or add a code to match the Contact to the User. This way, you won't have issues with users with the same name or typo's.

Please find below your workflow activity converted to a Pre-Operation plugin.

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace KED365.Plugins
{
    public class CreateUpdateContact : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            var factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            var service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            tracingService.Trace("Start plugin");

            tracingService.Trace("Validate Target");
            if (!context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") || !(context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity))
                return;

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieve Target");
            var target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            String message = context.MessageName.ToLower();

            SetCreatedByAndModifiedBy(tracingService, service, target, message);
        }

        private void SetCreatedByAndModifiedBy(ITracingService tracingService, IOrganizationService service, Entity target, string message)
        {
            tracingService.Trace("Start SetPriceList");
            tracingService.Trace("Validate Message is Create or Update");
            if (!message.Equals("create", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !message.Equals("update", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return;

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieve Attributes");
            var createdByReference = target.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_createdby");
            var modifiedByReference = target.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_modifiedby");

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieve And Set User for Created By");
            RetrieveAndSetUser(tracingService, service, target, createdByReference, "createdby");

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieve And Set User for Modified By");
            RetrieveAndSetUser(tracingService, service, target, modifiedByReference, "modifiedby");
        }

        private void RetrieveAndSetUser(ITracingService tracingService, IOrganizationService service, Entity target, EntityReference reference, string targetAttribute)
        {
            tracingService.Trace("Validating Reference");
            if (reference == null)
                return;

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieving and Validating User");
            var user = RetrieveUserByName(service, reference.Name, new ColumnSet(false));
            if (user == null)
                return;

            tracingService.Trace("Setting Target Attribute");
            target[targetAttribute] = user.ToEntityReference();
        }

        private Entity RetrieveUserByName(IOrganizationService service, string name, ColumnSet columns)
        {
            var query = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "systemuser",
                ColumnSet = columns,
                Criteria = new FilterExpression
                {
                    FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                    Conditions =
                    {
                        new ConditionExpression
                        {
                            AttributeName = "fullname",
                            Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                            Values = { name }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var retrieveResponse = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
            if (retrieveResponse.Entities.Count == 1)
            {
                return retrieveResponse.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                // Alternatively you can thrown an error as you have unexpectedly multiple matches
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I was able to register the pre-operation plug-in.  However, the "Modified By" field still is not being updated.  Do I need to create a workflow or something else now that it is registered?  Or should the plugin run automatically now that it is registered?
Also, the "Prepared By" field gets populated automatically, but it usually happens a few seconds after the record is created.  Could this be why the "Modified By" field isn't updating?
Lastly, I'm wondering if it would help if I used a pre-validation plug-in instead of a pre-operation plug-in?

Comment: Hello Tim, Please turn on Plugin Tracing in the System Settings and review the PluginTrace's (entity in Dynamics CRM) to see what the plugin did or did not do. I assume it does not find a match because of a bug in my code or because the names do not match. Will need to debug this, it should work.